# Is there a limitation on reading files in in c#

Tags: c#

I find all the functions which  reads data from files, such as 
BinaryReader.Read Bytes() , FileStream.Read() etc  to have read count  as type "int" ,which means we could read files only up-to a maximum of 2^32 bytes of data , which again translates to 4GB of data. 
I see this as a limitation in c# as the count must be of long type.
Is there any reason behind such a restriction on handling files greater than 4GB?

Comment: The same limitation is everywhere else, you can't have a byte array of more than 2GB in size either. Note that `int` is signed, so the limit is 2GB, not 4 (half is below zero). But, do you *really* need to read more than 2GB in one go into memory?

Comment: Regardless of language, loading 4 gigabytes would take a lot of time and keeping them in memory could lead to thrashing. You'd have to find a way around keeping all of these in consecutive memory, anyway. You could make a collection that internally breaks the data to chunks, in order to achieve what you want: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5bb9e0d-836a-44df-b4b6-0f3388c1f8de/huge-byte-array?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read more than 500 MB it's time to think about streaming the file into memory a piece at a time. In extreme circumstances this is very difficult, you may want to consider other file formats, which are easier to stream.
Trivial examples are mp3 and most if not all video formats.
If the file is in a custom format you may want to modify the format so that streaming is possible or at least easier and more reliable. But that's a completely different question.

Also, some file systems cannot support more than 1 GB, others are stuck at 4 GB. Modern FS (NTFS and current Linux FSs) have higher limits. Someone here on SO will surely tell you all ins and outs if you ask for more info.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the size of file that can be read. If you want to read more bytes than can be counted by an int, just call Read() multiple times.

And for what it is worth, int is signed so the maximum value is 2GB.